# Linq Query to filter Table 1 and get count from Table 2

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have 2 tables, one Orders and one Products.  The Orders has OrderID, OrderName and AccessID, whilst the Products has ProductID, ProductName and OrderID.  These tables have more fields but these are the relevant ones for my problem.

So what I wish to do is, get the first set of products in the products table with their OrderID, which order has less than 8 products, and the AccessID is 1.

I know that I can do it in 2 LINQ statements, first filter by AccessID in Orders, and then create a loop in the products table to get the first instance of Count < 8, however I am sure there is a better way to do this, possibly in 1 statement.

Thanks for your help and time

This is what I have come up with for now and still has to be tested :-

```
    public Order OrdersLessThanEightItems()
    {
        IEnumerable<int> orderId = null;
        int accessID = 1;

        Order order = (from o in db.Orders
                                     where o.AccessID == accessID && o.Products.Count < 8                                         
                                     orderby o.Products.Count ascending 
                                     select o).FirstOrDefault();
        return order;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pre Edit**

Shouldn't the relationship between orders and products be a many to many relationship?

Should product have OrderID? Then 1 product will only allowed to be in 1 order.

**Post Edit** (after highlighting that the relationship is 1 to many)

```
public class Product 
{
   //...
   public Order InOrder { get; set; }
   //...
}

public class Order
{
   //...
   public virtual ICollection<Product> ProductsInOrder { get; set; }
   //...
}
```

Then you'll be able to use this (untested):

```
List<Product> productList = (from o in context.Orders
                             where o.AccessID == myAccessID && o.ProductsInOrder.Count < 8
                             orderby o.ProductsInOrder.Count
                             select o).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi The Power, in my case, its a 1 to 1 relationship, ie a Product can only be in 1 order at any time.

Comment: @Johann If it's a 1 to 1 relationship there will never be more than 1 product in an order.

Comment: Oh sorry what I meant is that if a product is in an order, than that product cannot be in another order, so its 1 to many between order and products.  I have come up with something which still needs to be tested though, and will edit my question

Comment: @Johann I've altered the code to match your 1 to many relationship.

Comment: Hi The Power I have actually used your first example cause it worked better, however I still have a slight problem.  If for example Order 1 has 2 items and order 2 has 4 items, I want to retreive order 2, which has the most items less than 8.  You can see my new code in this post

Comment: The orderby will order them by number of items, this will put those with the least to the top. So the order with the least items will be at index 0 (but check if the count is > 0 first).

Comment: so how can I put the ones with the most at the top?

Comment: orderby o.ProductsInOrder.Count descending